# pass clicked elements href as a parameter in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I can't figure out a way how to do something like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com" ng-click="myFunc(this.href)">Link</a>
```

So essentially I want to pass href of clicked link as a parameter for `myFunc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="http://google.com/" ng-click="myFunc($event.target.href)">Link</a>
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19927/)